# How can I escape HTML in a Rails 3.1 controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

`h` / `html_escape` don’t work within a controller method.

I know, it’s for views. (Or was — haven’t done much Rails since v2.3). But I’m just building an eensy-weensy string and want to use this method in my controller.

So how can I escape HTML from within a controller method?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[`ERB::Util.html_escape`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape)

You can `include ERB::Util` in your controller to use these methods directly.